# Error Return type less accessible than method in ArcGIS

Tags: c#, object

I have written a code in visual studio for AR but it kept giving me this error, i tried changing them from private to public but didn't work, please have a look:

This is class 1:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
      private ARSceneView _arView;
      private CalibrationViewController _calibrationVC;
      ----
      ----
      _calibrationVC = new CalibrationViewController(_arView, _locationSource);
     }
```

class 2

```
public class CalibrationViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private ARSceneView _arView;
        private Loc _locationSource;// Loc is class where location is taken from
        ***public CalibrationViewController(ARSceneView arView, Loc locationSource)
        {
            _arView = arView;
            _locationSource = locationSource;
        }***
       -----------
    }
```

The *** part is where the error keeps pointing me to.
I have also attached the error message too..

*Error  CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Loc' is less accessible than method 'CalibrationViewController.CalibrationViewController(ARSceneView, Loc)'*

Comment: Well presumably either `Loc` or `ARSceneView` is internal, so you can't have that as a parameter type in a public constructor of a public class...

Comment: Now that you've added the error message in: yes, `Loc` is an internal type. So either make it public, or make the constructor of `CalibrationViewController` internal.

Comment: Making it internal fixed the error thank you